# ruby - problem converting http response body from xml to hash - missing attribute quote error

Tags: ruby, xml, hashtable

I am having trouble converting an http response body from XML to hash in ruby. I'm interacting with the Soalrwinds Orion API.

```
def submitCorePluginConfigRequest()
  corePluginContext = [{"name":"item 1"},{"name": "item2}]
  uri = URI.parse("https://examplesolarwinds.com:17778/SolarWinds/InformationService/v3/Json/Invoke/Orion.Discovery/CreateCorePluginConfiguration")

  http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
  http.use_ssl = true
  http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE

  request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.request_uri, initheader = { "Content-Type" => "application/json" })
  request.body = corePluginContext.to_json
  request.basic_auth("username", "password")

  response = http.request(request)
  hash_response = Hash.from_xml(response.body)

  return hash_response
end
```

The `Hash.from_xml` errors with `missing attribute quote (REXML::ParseException)`

The `response.body` (formatted) is as follows:

```
"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-16\"?>
<PluginItems>
    <knownTypes>
        <ArrayOfstring
            xmlns:i=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\"
            xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays\">
            <string>SolarWinds.Orion.Core.Models.Discovery.CoreDiscoveryPluginConfiguration,SolarWinds.Orion.Core.Models.V1</string>
        </ArrayOfstring>
    </knownTypes>
    <pluginItem>
        <ArrayOfDiscoveryPluginConfigurationBase
            xmlns:i=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\"
            xmlns=\"http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/SolarWinds.Orion.Core.Models.Discovery\">
            <DiscoveryPluginConfigurationBase
                xmlns:d2p1=\"http://schemas.solarwinds.com/2008/Orion\" i:type=\"d2p1:CoreDiscoveryPluginConfiguration\">
                <d2p1:ActiveDirectoryList />
                <d2p1:AddressRange />
                <d2p1:AgentsAddresses
                    xmlns:d3p1=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays\" />
                    <d2p1:AutoImportVolumeTypes
                        xmlns:d3p1=\"http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/SolarWinds.Common.Snmp\" i:nil=\"true\" />
                        <d2p1:BulkList
                            xmlns:d3p1=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays\">
                            <d3p1:string>10.83.4.77</d3p1:string>
                        </d2p1:BulkList>
                        <d2p1:Credentials>
                            <d2p1:credentials>
                                <knownTypes>
                                    <ArrayOfstring
                                        xmlns:i=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\"
                                        xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays\" />
                                    </knownTypes>
                                    <pluginItem>
                                        <d2p1:ArrayOfCredential
                                            xmlns:i=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" />
                                        </pluginItem>
                                    </d2p1:credentials>
                                </d2p1:Credentials>
                                <d2p1:DiscoverAgentNodes>false</d2p1:DiscoverAgentNodes>
                                <d2p1:PreferredPollingMethod>SNMP</d2p1:PreferredPollingMethod>
                                <d2p1:SharedCredentials
                                    xmlns:d3p1=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays\" />
                                    <d2p1:SubnetList />
                                    <d2p1:WMICredentials />
                                    <d2p1:WmiRetries>0</d2p1:WmiRetries>
                                    <d2p1:WmiRetryInterval>PT1S</d2p1:WmiRetryInterval>
                                </DiscoveryPluginConfigurationBase>
                            </ArrayOfDiscoveryPluginConfigurationBase>
                        </pluginItem>
                    </PluginItems>"
```

When I copy this xml and declare it as a string explicitly, (i.e. `testxml = above xml`), `Hash.from_xml(testxml)` works fine and outputs hash.
The above xml is valid and the `response.body` has quotes so I can't figure out why it says its missing a quote.
I have tried using `response.parsed_response`, I have tried using `response.body.to_s`, I have tried using XML simple.

Comment: The answer to your problem will be in the question: what is the difference between the copy pasted version, and `response.body`. There's not enough information in your question to solve this without an answer to that question, and once you solve that question, you will most likely find your solution :)

Comment: My question is why am I getting the error when I try to convert the `response.body` to hash and why is it different from the copy pasted version.
Is there a way to force `response.body` into a string object that is different than `response.body.to_s`? I feel like if I can get `reponse.body` to behave as a string, it will convert to hash just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found something that worked for me.

After the request, I tried using the JSON parser:

```
json_response = JSON.parse(response.body)
```

But this just turned the response body into slightly different xml, not JSON.
But then using that different xml, `hash_response = Hash.from_xml(json_response)` worked to turn the response into hash.

Not entirely sure whats going on with all this, but it works.